# Calling .stop() on AppiumDriverLocalService fails

Tags: java, android, appium

I have written few automated tests for an Android application Everything works fine except that when I stop the AppiumDriverLocalService after the test is done it breaks.....

Here is the code (written using JUnit)

```
@AfterClass
public  static  void stopServer(){
    service.stop();  //this is where the code breaks
}
```

And the stack trace

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Kernel32

at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils.killWinProcess(ProcessUtils.java:133)
at org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils.killProcess(ProcessUtils.java:81)
at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog.destroyHarder(UnixProcess.java:247)
at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog.access$2(UnixProcess.java:246)
at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess.destroy(UnixProcess.java:125)
at org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.destroy(CommandLine.java:153)
at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService.destroyProcess(AppiumDriverLocalService.java:141)
at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService.stop(AppiumDriverLocalService.java:135)
at com.example.MyTests.stopServer(MyTests.java:69)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:33)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32
```

An it strangely creates another test case in my class called "Class Configuration", which I have not written.

[image]

Am I missing some jar file? I am pretty sure something is missing. Please shed some light on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is due to missing jar(In your project's reference libraries) that contains :

```
com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Kernel32
```

You should be able to download it with its dependency here:

```
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjna330platformjar.htm
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjna330jar.htm
```

And import them to your project.

also the way you are stopping the service, it's wrong as it might be the case that your service is already terminated due to some other reasons. please use below code to check if service actually exists or not.

```
private void stopAppiumServer() {
            if (service != null) {
            service.stop();
            System.out.println("Appium Server Stopped");
        }
```

Comment: download the jar and put it where? I have seen this answer before, but couldn't get to know where to put the jar file...

Comment: @HorribleGuy - Fix is same in both the cases, i thought you will understand it. so, to make my answer more clear for you i have updated the answer. please try and let me know if it works for you.